# Getting "unauthorized" error when trying to refresh access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to refresh the access token for a user following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-remember-me).

However, I am getting

```
{
    "error":"unauthorized",
    "error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

and I do not see what's missing.

The following is how I am constructing the `oauth/refresh` request in my Angular application:

```js
refreshToken() {

  this.logger.info('Attempting to refresh access token');

  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')
    // CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET
    .set('Authorization', 'Basic Q0xJRU5UX0lEOkNMSUVOVF9TRUNSRVQ='); 

  const payload = {
    refresh_token: AuthenticationService.getRefreshToken(),
    grant_type: 'refresh_token'
  };

  return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/oauth/refresh',
    payload, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(r => r));
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was *almost* right.

First, I did use the wrong endpoint `/oauth/refresh` - I don't know why I thought this existed. It has to be `/oauth/token`.

Also payload gets send via URL parameters:

```
const payload = `refresh_token=${AuthenticationService.getRefreshToken()}&grant_type=refresh_token`;
```

So in the end I got this working with:

```
refreshToken() {

  this.logger.info('Attempting to refresh access token');

  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')
    .set('Authorization', 'Basic Q0xJRU5UX0lEOkNMSUVOVF9TRUNSRVQ=');

  const payload = `refresh_token=${AuthenticationService.getRefreshToken()}&grant_type=refresh_token`;

  return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/oauth/token',
    payload, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(r => r));
}
```